# QSW (Quebec Skilled Workers) program area of training points

Tags: visa, canada, immigration, resident-permit

I applied for the QSW (Quebec Skilled Workers) program last May 2014. Based on my previous assessment, I am eligible for the program. I got my file number last August 2014. Unfortunately, the Quebec province has issued changes with regards to points in area of training. Am I affected by the changes? Are my attained previous points affected?

Comment: I believe they should normally inform you of changes to your status, or of new rules that might affect you